# Is there any way to find out total number of simple graphs of given sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This problem came randomly to my mind while studying graph theory.Suppose 3,3,3,3,3,3 is a given sequence of degree of vertices of a graph.We know one of its graph is a hexagon with opposite diagonals attached.But suppose any arbitrary sequence is given and suppose it is guaranteed that it's graph exists,then how to find all such graphs(I mean is there some algorithm or we have to find those graphs randomly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed. There is a paper on it here :

Zoltán Király ["Recognizing graphic degree sequences and generating all realizations"](http://www.cs.elte.hu/egres/tr/egres-11-11.ps)

Note that this approach will list multiple isomorphic copies of the graphs for a sequence - that is, it is redundant - but it will list them all (it is exhaustive).

With thanks to [Peter Erdos](https://users.renyi.hu/~elp/pub.html), who pointed me to this paper.